True sentences and Provable sentences
I came back to nonstandard analysis after a while, and I noticed something I hadn't noticed the first time I studied the subject.
Namely, a key result coming from Łoś's Theorem states that a sentence expressed in the language of real numbers (that is, using only real constants, functions, and relations) is true in the real numbers if and only if its "translation" into the language of hyperreal numbers (i.e., switching real constants, functions, and relations with the corresponding hyperreal constants and corresponding hyperreal extensions of functions and relations) is true.
However, this does not say anything about provability. For example, there could be a result about real numbers that is provable, but its hyperreal translation could be undecidable.
Don't we know anything about the relationship between provable statements?
Am I missing something?

Conservativity results for axiomatic nonstandard analysis provide such a relation.  For example, Nelson's Internal Set Theory (IST) is conservative over ZFC.  This means that given a proof of a (ZFC-expressible) proposition P in IST, there exists a proof of P in ZFC.
The work of Sam Sanders may be relevant here, such as his article

Sanders, Sam.
The unreasonable effectiveness of nonstandard analysis.
J. Logic Comput. 30 (2020), no. 1, 459–524.

Here the approach is that, given a proposition P of a certain form and a proof thereof in a suitable nonstandard system, there exists an algorithmic translation of the proof in traditional (non-infinitesimal) terms, furnishing effective estimates.

This is a very interesting paper, thank you for pointing it out!
